# Canon LBP5050 doesnt print in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon

I've installedand configured my printer many times with this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190

I've tried 2.4 and 2.3 drivers but noticed no difference. At first installed by using guide to 12.04 as I have that version on ubuntu. Then tried the longer version. And mixed them up and googled a lot.

Now I'm in situation that captstatusui doesn't show anything at all. Gui launches but all fields are empty. When I try to print a test page it tries to process a while and gives me this error message: ccp send_data error, exit

Answer (score 0):

Type these commands into terminal after fresh boot before printing.

```
sudo modprobe usblp
ls -l /dev/usb/lp0
sudo ccpd start
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest turboprint (http://www.turboprint.info/). It is not payfree, but also it's only thing that makes my Canon IP1500 to work in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to install LBP5050n into Ubuntu 12.04 and works fine. But use rather:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP5050 -m CNCUPSLBP5050CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E
```

instead of:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP5000 -m CNCUPSLBP5000CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E
```